# How do we construct an action on a superspace lattice?

Tags: action, lattice-model, superspace-formalism

I am interested in the formulation of supersymmetric theories on a discrete spacetime, such as a lattice. I know that there are some difficulties in preserving supersymmetry on a lattice, such as the fermion doubling problem and the breaking of translational invariance. However, I have also heard that there are some approaches that can overcome these issues, such as orbifolding, twisted supersymmetry, and topological field theory methods.

My questions are :

How do we construct an action on a superspace lattice ?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of different approaches? How do we ensure that the action is invariant under supersymmetry transformations?

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Working with supersymmetric theories on the lattice is one thing. But claiming that the lattice actually lives in superspace is quite another. As far as I know, the methods you refer to preserve one scalar supercharge, not the spinor worth of supercharges needed to define superspace.

Comment: @ConnorBehan What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the methods you refer to have to do supersymmetric theories on an ordinary (non-superspace) lattice.

Answer (score 2):

As Connor Behan points out, what people normally do is put a supersymmetric theory on a lattice in ordinary space-time. The idea of a lattice *in superspace* is highly unusual. (By the way, "superspace lattice" is also a term in crystallography that has nothing to do with supersymmetry.)

However, I have found at least two approaches to doing this.

One approach is due to Kostelecky and Rabin. Their most cited paper on this subject is ["Supersymmetry on a Superlattice"](https://inspirehep.net/literature/13533).

The second approach is due to Michio Kaku! His most cited paper on this subject is ["Gauge Theory on a Random Supersymmetric Lattice"](https://inspirehep.net/literature/195123). He insists on calling a supersymmetric lattice, a "slattice", which I suppose is no worse than slepton or squark.

Both papers are from 1983 and have very few citations. I haven't even read them yet and can't judge if there is any substance to them. But they do both construct an action, which is what you say you're after.

The idea of a lattice in superspace is rather interesting. It sounds like it deserves study using advanced methods. [Rabin's subsequent works](https://inspirehep.net/authors/992496) on supermanifolds and super Riemann surfaces might be worth a look, and maybe the latter could be compared with Albert Schwarz's notion of a superconformal manifold.